# How to implement Apache Beam UDF for Calcite SQL?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I'm trying to implement a simple BitwiseAnd as a UDF for SQL in my Apache Beam pipeline. Here is the simple code snippet

```
public static class BitwiseAnd implements BeamSqlUdf {
    public static Integer eval(Integer input, Integer bit){
        return input & bit;
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
No match found for function signature BitwiseAnd(<NUMERIC>, <NUMERIC>)
```

I've also tried with with `Long` in the method signature and get the following error

> No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.Integer, long"; candidates are: "public static java.lang.Long SqlTest$BitwiseAnd.eval(java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long)"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the context you are using this UDF in is expecting the signature to be

```
public static Integer eval(Integer input, Long bit) { ... }
```

You could also cast one side to match the type of the other before the UDF as well.